# What's the difference in process handling

Tags: vhdl

Explain like i'm five, please, what's the real difference between

```
process (a,b)
begin
if rising_edge (a) then
--my code here
end if;
if rising_edge (b) then
--my code here
end if;
end process;
```

and

```
process (a)
begin
if rising_edge (a) then
--my code here
end if;
end process;
process (b)
begin
if rising_edge (b) then
--my code here
end if;
end process;
```

used in the same architecture.
upd.: difference using two signals in one process, and separate processes for each signal

Comment: Did you mean for the second example to not have any `rising_edge` statements?

Comment: Are any assignment targets in common between the two `--my code here segments`? This doesn't present a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), nor a clear problem statement. The difference between them is one is a single process and the other is comprised of two processes. In what context there difference may have meaning isn't clear from your question.

Comment: The first process can be used to describe a dual clocked memory element like a Xilinx BlockRAM with dual port/dual clock interface. But not all synthesizers recognize this pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just talking about how the language is defined (in other words, what a simulator does, or should do), then the answer is 'very little'. The scope is different - the two code blocks in your first example can share an ordinary variable, for example, but that's about it. The process in your first example fires on any event on either a or b, and then a and b are tested in turn. This happens independently for the 2 processes in your second example. The answer would be different if your processes contained any wait statements, but they're not allowed to in this example.

What I think you're missing is that simulation and synthesis are different. A synthesiser doesn't carry out a a simulation to decide what a description does, or should do. It's a completely static procedure which relies on heuristics and template searches in your code, which means that it will only understand a subset of the language. And it won't understand your first example, because there are standardised ways of describing clocked hardware, and this isn't one of them.

Paebbels - I would be very surprised if any synthesiser could handle the first example; feel free to tell me that I'm wrong. Both XST and Quartus can apparently infer dual-clocked memory elements when two different processes write to the same shared variable, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I have used the first coding style in the past for dual clocked memories as @Paebbels suggests and it has worked fine - have not tested it recently.  It is compliant with 1076.6-2004.  And while the supported coding styles with shared variables may be 1076-1993 compliant, they are no longer language compliant after VHDL-2000/2002.   Perhaps FPGA vendors should petition the VHDL committee to make them compliant again?  However if they stay quiet, it will not happen.

Comment: Our [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) has a [PoC.mem.ocram.tdp](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/ocram_tdp.vhdl#L145-L166) component that uses this style. Is tested in XST 14.7, Vivado 2015.2 and Quartus-II (using altsyncram) and iSim, xSim, vSim and GHDL :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on "my code" there may be a difference in behavior if a and b rises at the same time. In the combined process you know that the a code will run before the b code but when you split the process into two you don't know the order anymore. This may make a difference if the two code blocks share some resource. For example, if one is writing into a shared variable while the other is reading. In that case you don't know if the old or new value will be read.